Text Box Being Cropped JavaFX
I am designing a timer application. Here is my JavaFX code:
package com.jammin.timetimer;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage PrimaryStage) {
        //Adds all the necessary elements into the window

        StackPane myStackPane = new StackPane();

        VBox myVBox = new VBox(myStackPane);
        myVBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        HBox myHBox = new HBox(myVBox);
        myHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene myScene = new Scene(myHBox, 400,400);

        ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(new Image("file:src/main/resources/img/timer_ticks.png"));
        myImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(myScene.heightProperty());
        myImageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(myScene.widthProperty());
        myImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        myStackPane.getChildren().addAll(myImageView);

        Arc myArc = createArc(myStackPane, myScene);

        TextField myTextField = createTextField(myArc, myScene);

        myVBox.getChildren().add(myTextField);

        PrimaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        PrimaryStage.show();
        System.out.println(myVBox.fillWidthProperty());
    }

    //Constructor for my Arc
    public Arc createArc(StackPane myStackPane, Scene myScene){
        Arc myArc = new Arc(100,100,100,100,0,360);
        myArc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        myArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        myStackPane.getChildren().add(myArc);

       myScene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number t1) {
                if (t1.doubleValue() <= myScene.getHeight()*1.05){
                    myArc.setRadiusX(t1.doubleValue()/2.9);
                    myArc.setRadiusY(t1.doubleValue()/2.9);
                }
            }
        });

        myScene.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number t1) {
                if (t1.doubleValue() <= myScene.getWidth()){
                    myArc.setRadiusX(t1.doubleValue()/2.9);
                    myArc.setRadiusY(t1.doubleValue()/2.9);
                }
            }
        });

        return myArc;
    }

    //Textfield to enter the time
    public TextField createTextField(Arc myArc, Scene myScene){
        TextField myTextField = new TextField("Enter Time 1-60");
        myTextField.setMinHeight(myScene.getHeight()*.1);

        TextFormatter<Integer> myTextFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 60, this::filter);

        myTextField.setTextFormatter(myTextFormatter);

       // myTextField.setOnAction((evt) -> myArc.setLength(myTextFormatter.getValue()!=null ? 6*myTextFormatter.getValue():0));

        return myTextField;
    }

    //Filter to only allow for use of time between 1-60minutes
    public TextFormatter.Change filter(TextFormatter.Change myChange){
        if (myChange.getControlNewText().isEmpty()){
            return myChange;
        }
        int myVal = Integer.parseInt(myChange.getControlNewText());

        return myVal >=0 && myVal <= 60 ? myChange : null;
    }
}

However, I do not like that the resizing allows the textbox to get cutoff:

Does anyone know of a way to fix this issue? I am wondering if it has to do with the functions I use to resize the window? But I have tried adjusting the values without any success... I don't plan to keep the text box in future versions of this application, but I do plan to put a menu button, so I want to figure out this problem sooner than later.

You have myImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(myScene.heightProperty()); (among other things), which essentially forces the behavior you don't want.

You have the following line
        myImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(myScene.heightProperty());

which attempts to force the height of the image view to be the full height of the scene. This leaves no room at all for the text field. The layout algorithm for the VBox will attempt to compromise when there is not enough space for all the child nodes, reducing the height of each of them. Consequently both the image view and the text field are reduced in height, so both of them are cropped, though this is only apparent for the text field (probably there is empty space around the image).
Generally it is a bad idea to use bindings on the sizes of parent nodes to control the size of child nodes as a way to manage layout. Changing the size of a child node will change the preferred size of its parent, and then the binding will force a recalculation of the size of the child node. While you may get away with this, in some cases this can force a recalculation of the layout on every layout pulse. For an extreme example (where an image view constantly grows in size), see here.
Generally for layout you should layout managed, resizable nodes by placing them in an appropriate layout pane (VBox, BorderPane) etc, and manage the (non-trivial) layout of non-resizable nodes (shapes and text, etc.) by using a custom Region, sizing and positioning them in the layoutChildren() method.
I would not recommend using an image for the numbers and tick marks on your timer: just use Text and Line objects. Place them, along with the arc, in a custom Region and position them in the layoutChildren() method.
Here is a reasonably production-ready implementation. I just hard-coded the space required for the numbers and used the default font, but you could compute the space needed by the texts and even resize the font accordingly if you wanted the numbers to increase/decrease in size as the containing pane was resized. (I also put the numbers in what I think is a more natural order; if you want them backwards, as in the OP, you can just change the assignment of angle in layoutChildren().)

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TimerView extends Region {
    private final Arc arc;
    private final List<Line> ticks;
    private final List<Text> numbers;

    private static final double MINOR_TICK_LENGTH = 3;
    private static final double MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH = 6;
    private static final double NUMBER_PADDING = 30;

    private static final double PREF_TIMER_RADIUS = 100;
    private static final double MIN_TIMER_RADIUS = 100;

    private final DoubleProperty time = new SimpleDoubleProperty(60);

    public DoubleProperty timeProperty() {
        return time;
    }

    public final void setTime(double time) {
        timeProperty().set(time);
    }

    public final double getTime() {
        return timeProperty().get();
    }


    public TimerView() {
        arc = new Arc();
        arc.setStartAngle(90);
        arc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        arc.lengthProperty().bind(timeProperty().multiply(-6));

        ticks = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            Line tick = new Line();
            if (i % 5 == 0) { // major tick:
                tick.setStrokeWidth(2);
                Text number = new Text(String.valueOf(i));
                number.setTextOrigin(VPos.CENTER);
                numbers.add(number);
            }
            ticks.add(tick);
        }

        getChildren().add(arc);
        getChildren().addAll(ticks);
        getChildren().addAll(numbers);

    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double ti = snappedTopInset();
        double ri = snappedRightInset();
        double bi = snappedBottomInset();
        double li = snappedLeftInset();
        double availableWidth = getWidth() - li - ri;
        double availableHeight = getHeight() - ti - bi;
        double centerX = li + availableWidth / 2;
        double centerY = ti + availableHeight / 2;

        double radius = Math.min(availableWidth / 2, availableHeight / 2);
        double arcRadius = radius - MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH - NUMBER_PADDING;

        arc.setCenterX(centerX);
        arc.setCenterY(centerY);
        arc.setRadiusX(arcRadius);
        arc.setRadiusY(arcRadius);

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            double angle = -Math.PI / 2 + 2 * Math.PI * i / 60;
            Line tick = ticks.get(i);
            double c = Math.cos(angle);
            double s = Math.sin(angle);
            tick.setStartX(centerX + arcRadius * c);
            tick.setStartY(centerY + arcRadius * s);
            if (i % 5 == 0) { // major tick
                tick.setEndX(centerX + (arcRadius + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH) * c);
                tick.setEndY(centerY + (arcRadius + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH) * s);
                Text number = numbers.get(i / 5);
                double numberWidth = number.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
                number.setX(centerX - numberWidth / 2 + (arcRadius + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH + NUMBER_PADDING / 2) * c);
                number.setY(centerY + (arcRadius + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH + NUMBER_PADDING / 2) * s);
            } else {
                tick.setEndX(centerX + (arcRadius + MINOR_TICK_LENGTH) * c);
                tick.setEndY(centerY + (arcRadius + MINOR_TICK_LENGTH) * s);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return snappedLeftInset() + snappedRightInset() +
                2 * (NUMBER_PADDING + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH + PREF_TIMER_RADIUS);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return snappedTopInset() + snappedBottomInset() +
                2 * (NUMBER_PADDING + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH + PREF_TIMER_RADIUS);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMinWidth(double height) {
        return snappedLeftInset() + snappedRightInset() +
                2 * (NUMBER_PADDING + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH + MIN_TIMER_RADIUS);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computeMinHeight(double width) {
        return snappedTopInset() + snappedBottomInset() +
                2 * (NUMBER_PADDING + MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH + MIN_TIMER_RADIUS);
    }
}

And here is it used in more or less the same application example provided in the OP:

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.IntegerStringConverter;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TimerView timerView = new TimerView();
        root.setCenter(timerView);

        TextField myTextField = createTextField(timerView);

        root.setBottom(myTextField);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    //Textfield to enter the time
    public TextField createTextField(TimerView timer){
        TextField myTextField = new TextField("Enter Time 1-60");

        TextFormatter<Integer> myTextFormatter = new TextFormatter<>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 60, this::filter);

        myTextField.setTextFormatter(myTextFormatter);

        timer.timeProperty().bind(myTextFormatter.valueProperty());

        return myTextField;
    }

    //Filter to only allow for use of time between 1-60minutes
    public TextFormatter.Change filter(TextFormatter.Change myChange){
        String newText = myChange.getControlNewText();
        if (newText.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            if (myChange.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
                return myChange;
            }
            int myVal = Integer.parseInt(myChange.getControlNewText());
            if (myVal >= 0 && myVal <= 60) {
                return myChange;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}

Because the timer is in the center of a border pane, it will be resized to take remaining available space (after allocating space to the text field), and the layoutChildren() method will let the arc fill the available space. So increasing the size of the window will result in increasing the size of the timer. Other layouts can be used and configured to create the same effect (e.g. a VBox with fillWidth=true and VBox.setVgrow(timer, Priority.ALWAYS)).

